# How do I work around a bad video card in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, graphics-card

I've got a computer that runs Minecraft without problem, and a couple of others that don't even let me try because of "bad video card drivers". The cards are too old -- updating drivers doesn't fix the problem. Is there a way to override this check that Minecraft does? Would a remote-desktop solution be plausible?

Comment: I've got the same issue on my desktop computer.

Comment: I could add that it is an ATI Rage 128 card, but that shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: For those with newer video cards that should work, check out this thread on minecraftforums.net which talks about drivers and how to update them: http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=39953

Comment: @Matthew: That's not the case here, though.

Comment: I know, Hyppy already has the answer for you.  But others will come across this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that it requires hardware-accelerated OpenGL with driver extensions to support it. If one of those computers has an Intel graphics chipset, installing the Intel version instead of the built-in Windows one usually fixes it.

Rage128 only supports OpenGL 1.2, but Minecraft requires 2.0. It just won't work with that card, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try the In-Browser version... I get the same issues on one of my computer's but the In-Browser version works ok.

http://www.minecraft.net/game/

Comment: Weird, it gives me the same issue, in-browser or not.